# Skype webcam audio not working since 17.04 upgrade

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, skype, webcam, microphone

I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04 a few days ago and since then the webcam mic has not worked with Skype - either the old version or the new Skype for Linux Beta. If I open the Pulse Audio Volume Control panel I can see the microphone input is detected but Skype does not recognize it. The headphones do work with Skype. My Webcam is (from lsusb)

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:081b Logitech, Inc. Webcam C310

Comment: I reran tests with both the HP and my old Dell, using the Webcams C310 and E2500. Here are the results:
Dell (32 bit with Lubuntu 17.04):
Neither webcam works.
Dell with Windows 10: 
Both webcams work.
HP Pavilion (64 bit with Xubuntu 17.04):
Neither webcam works in Skype, though the microphone is clearly detecting my voice, as shown on Pulse Audio Volume Control.
HP with Windows 10:
Both webcams work.

Comment: Webcam C310 works with Xubuntu 16.04.2 on my HP.